# Elasticsearch boolean query doesn't work with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not very strong in Elasticsearch. I'm trying to set up search in my app and got some strange problems. I have two documents:

```js
{
  "title": "Second insight"
  "content": "Bla bla bla"
  "library": "workspace"
}
{
  "title": "Test source"
  "content": "Bla bla bla"
  "library": "workspace"
}
```

Then, I want to be able to make a search by text fields like `title` and `content` and apply some filters on fields like `library`. I have a query:

```js
{
    "query": {
      "bool": { 
        "should": [
          { "match": { "title": "insight" }}
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "library": "workspace"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

Despite the fact that I clearly defined `title` to be matched to `insight`, the query above returns **both** documents, not only the first one.

If I remove `filter` block:

```js
{
    "query": {
      "bool": { 
        "should": [
          { "match": { "title": "insight" }}
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

the query returns correct results.

Then, I also tried to make a partial search. For some reasons, the query uses `ins` instead of `insight` below doesn't work, so, it returns empty list:

```js
{
    "query": {
      "bool": { 
        "should": [
          { "match": { "title": "ins" }}
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

How should I make partial search? And how can I set up filters correctly? In other words, how to make a search partial query by some fields, but at the same time filtered by other fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply `minimum_should_match` in your first query.

I did the following and only got a single document (your desired outcome)

```
POST test_things/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "insight"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "library": "workspace"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As for why `ins` doesn't work, it depends on your mapping + analyzer being used. You are matching against analyzed terms in the index, if you want to match against `ins` you need to change your analyzer (possibly using the [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)) or use a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).